# IndentationError: expected an indented block within nested for loop

Tags: python, indentation

I am not sure where my indentation error is with my code. I am getting this error:

```
  File "ex1.py", line 43
    if v == 'arista_eos':
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Here is the code that is giving me the error:

```
for line in devices:
    for k, v in line.items():
        if v == 'juniper_junos':
          try:
            net_conn = ConnectHandler(**line)
            config = net_conn.send_command("show config | display set")
            filename = net_conn.host + '_' + time
            with open(filename, mode='w') as f:
                cwd = os.getcwd()
                cfl = cwd + '/' + filename
                f.write(config)
                shutil.move(cfl, direct)
          except NoValidConnectionsError:
        if v == 'arista_eos':
          try:
            net_conn = ConnectHandler(**line)
            config = net_conn.send_command("show run")
            filename = net_conn.host + '_' + time
            with open(filename, mode='w') as f:
                cwd = os.getcwd()
                cfl = cwd + '/' + filename
                f.write(config)
                shutil.move(cfl, direct)
          except (NetMikoTimeoutException, NoValidConnectionsError, NameError):
```

Comment: Is there any reason why the 2nd line doesn't have an indentation ?

Comment: @K.vindi Yes, they didn't know how to format the code in their post properly and just added 4 spaces to the first line which seemingly made it look right.

Comment: Have you heard of `pass`? Do you understand what it is used for?

Comment: I have not heard of pass but was able to use it in my script and it is working fine now. Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>   except NoValidConnectionsError:
> if v == 'arista_eos':
> ```

After `except NoValidConnectionsError:` there must follow an indented block which specifies *what should happen* in case of a `NoValidConnectionsError`:

```
  except NoValidConnectionsError:
      # indented block here
if v == 'arista_eos':
```

You omitted that for some reason, which isn't valid.

Comment: @MikeF Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)